# What is the simplest way to turn a python script into a webapp?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I do programming as a hobby. I use java and python and I know HTML. I wrote the following python script. I want to turn it into a webapp. That is you go onto the webpage you press a button , the script runs on the server it picks wav files in a random order pieces them together and then I want the link to the wav file to appear on the webpage so that the user can play it. I also want the solutions to be displayed onto the webpage. I have looked into flask and and django and it is a bit daunting. It seems that it is all about databases and authentication I couldn't find a tutorial that would do something similar to what I am trying to do here. If you have any pointers I would be grateful. What should I look into ? What is the easiest solution for what I am trying to do. What technology should I use ?
 Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import wave
import random


def concatenate_multiple_files(infiles):
while len(infiles) >= 2:
    raw_files = infiles[0:2]
    outfile = "sound_to_play_in_browser.wav"
    data = []
    for infile in infiles:
        w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')
        data.append([w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())])
        w.close()
    output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
    output.setparams(data[0][0])
    output.writeframes(data[0][1])
    output.writeframes(data[1][1])
    output.close()
    infiles.pop(0)
    infiles.pop(0)
    infiles.insert(0, outfile)


def create_random_list_plus_solution(list_to_choose_from):
    random_list = []
    solutions = []
    while len(random_list) < 5:
       random_number = random.randrange(0, 5)
    if list_to_choose_from[random_number][0] not in random_list:
        random_list.append(list_to_choose_from[random_number][0])
        solutions.append(list_to_choose_from[random_number][1])
return [random_list, solutions]


infiles_plus_solutions = infiles = [["sound1.wav", "wolf"],
                                ["sound2.wav", "snake"],
                                ["sound3.wav", "bird"],
                                ["sound4.wav", "lion"],
                                ["sound5.wav", "cougar"],
                                ["sound6.wav", "cat"]
                                ]

outfile = "sound_to_play_in_browser.wav"

random_list_solutions = 
create_random_list_plus_solution(infiles_plus_solutions)
concatenate_multiple_files(random_list_solutions[0])
for i in random_list_solutions[1]:
    print(i)h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know why the question was downvoted. You essentially asked how to do an entire project, the question was not specific enough. I will try to help.

Break what you want to do into pieces. You will find that what you want is actually several things.

--You want your script running on a webpage that people can visit.

You are gonna have to host it somewhere. So look for those. A few places will let you host something simple like this for free. You need a web server. A framework like flask is pretty good for something this simple.

--You want a button which runs a script

You mentioned you know HTML. You can call your code inside Flask.

--You want to embed a media player on the page so the user can play the sample. 
You are gonna have to search for that. There should be solutions for this already. Maybe something like this : https://amazingaudioplayer.com/

You might not find a tutorial for the exact project you want to do, but if you break your project into sub-problems you will find they are almost always common. If you google for any of the problems by themselves, you should find plenty of resources.

Hope it helped a bit, I was not sure if anyone would answer because of the down votes. If you do have a specific question, do post again! Thanks.

Comment: Solid and polite answer. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Not a problem :)